# Fourier series in spherical coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, special-functions, fourier-series

I'm reading an article and he just state:

> let $f\left(\theta,\varphi\right)$ be of this form
>   $$f\left(\theta,\varphi\right)={\sum}g_{m}\left(\theta\right)e^{im\varphi},$$

I'm on the unitary sphere, may I say that all continuous functions may be written in this form or there's some assumptions underlying it? I guessed could be just something like the Fourier Series of a function in spherical coordinates but I didn't know the result.

Comment: Looks almost more like a decomposition into spherical harmonics...

Comment: It's the "normal" Fourier expansion in $\phi$ (at fixed $\theta$ if you want). Things get more complicated when you want to expand in both variables, then you need something like spherical harmonics.

Comment: http://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul954/KALF.PDF "It is less known that a function which is continuously differentiable on the unit sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be expanded in terms of a uniformly convergent series of spherical harmonics, a so–called Laplace series."